# Does partitioning a database table in Postgres mean there are several smaller databases or is there still just one?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are bench marking databases and one of the things we are looking at is the maximum number of rows we can store in Postgres in AWS.

The documentation states there can be a maximum of X rows where X = (32 * 1,099,511,627,776 / (how big the rows are in bytes)).

If we create partitions can they each have X rows or would it be X rows between them all?

Comment: There will be several smaller _tables_, not "databases".

Comment: So we can partition a table into two separate partitions and they could both contain 32 * 1,099,511,627,776 / (how big the rows are in bytes) rows?

Comment: Yes. But if you even get close to these numbers, you are probably doing something wrong. Use smaller partitions.